# divide two columns, not with each other

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, bc

I have a CSV file generated by a script of mine, It gets CPU time used per user, however it gets this in seconds, i need it in hours so i need to divide each line by 3600.

example input file

```
**USER,TOTAL_CPU,AVERAGE_CPU
user1,1234552.0,1234.3
user2,9999999.0,82772.6
user3,7777776227.9,282882,0**
```

I can easily get what i want if i do it one column at a time with:

```
for i in `awk -F , 'NR!=1{print $2}' myfile.out`; do bc -l <<< "scale=3; ($i/3600)"; done
```

That gives me the output for one column at a time. I want both at once, there has to be a better way, instead of working out one column, then the next and merging the two together. I want both at once, the output should look exactly  the same as the input but instead of seconds it will be in hours.

example output file:

```
USER,TOTAL_CPU,AVERAGE_CPU
user1,342.931,0.342
user2,2777.777,22.992
etc.....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
     NR > 1{
         $2 = sprintf("%.3f", $2/3600);
         $3 = sprintf("%.3f", $3/3600)
     }1' file
```

The output:

```
USER,TOTAL_CPU,AVERAGE_CPU
user1,342.931,0.343
user2,2777.778,22.992
user3,2160493.397,78.578,0
```